# ASP Textbox Label Font Color

Tags: asp.net, colors, textbox, label

I'm looking to change the font color of an ASP label applied to a textbox and am unsure of what property to use. In what I've shown below, I want to change the font color of "Student Search: " because I believe the default is black, but the label is on top of a black background and so I cannot currently see it.

```
<asp:Label id="label" AssociatedControlId="masterSearchBox" Text="Student Search: " 
    runat="server"/>

<asp:TextBox id="masterSearchBox" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Student Name..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS classes for controlling font colors and what have you. In your css file, put a class name and make sure that css file is referenced by your asp page.

```css
.YourClassName {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<asp:Label id="label" AssociatedControlId="masterSearchBox" Text="Student Search: " 
    runat="server" CssClass="YourClassName" />
```

Comment: I think you need to add background-color:#000; to your CSS rule to emulate the OP's situation.

Comment: This is showing how to set the font color of a label. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes but the snippet won't show it because the default background color is white. If you read the question you will see that the OP set the background color to black.